# VS Code - apply syntax hightlighting/formatting for custom file extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, formatting

I'm creating a little baseclass for webcomponents. For this I have created my own filetype (.wco => web components), divided in a  tag and a  tag. Now I face the problem that VS Code (logically) not know my custom file type, therefor it displays it as plain-text. How can I apply Typescript formatting/hightlighting  and CSS formatting/hightlighting for the same file? Is there a way to create an extension for this? Or is it already possible with prettier? How to define the language?

I'm not searching an answer for all questions of course, more  some hints into which direction I should look for. (Thinking about how svelte/vue does this?)

Any help is appreciated

Comment: setting: `files.associations`

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that we can add embedded languages with a language extension.
Information can be found here:

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide